# Aligning a photo after capturing it, for display wp7

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7, camera

I'm using camera task to take a picture then display it. I have an image control set to be the size 480 x 728, which is the size of the camera viewfinder. I'm telling the source of the image control to be the chosen photo after the picture is taken. The problem is that the picture is always horizontal instead of vertical. Which is good for if I was taking a landscape picture but not when I am taking one in portrait. I want it to fill the image control portrait if taken in portrait and vice versa. Does anyone have a fix for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to apply a transform to the image to correctly display the image, this is covered in the following blog post :-

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/23/working-with-pictures-in-camera-tasks-in-windows-phone-7-orientation-rotation.aspx